# Difference between the output with the paws and without?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
System.out.println("true");
      and 
System.out.println(true);
```

*Same with numbers*

```
 System.out.println("1");
       and
 System.out.println(1);
```

When output to the console, everything is transformed into a String. So I can not see the difference between it. Somebody can explain what is happening?

Comment: Try printing out `"maybe"` and `maybe`.

Comment: refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: What is your question? The final result is exactly the same? There is not difference in the output, so what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [method overloading](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) in Java.

Either you call

```
System.out.println("true");
```

or

```
System.out.println(true);
```

Both will print `true` on console.

**Reason behind this.** You need not to cast different primitive data types.

@Tejal refereed [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). You can see

> `println(boolean x)` Prints a boolean and then terminate the line.

and

> `println(String x)` Prints a String and then terminate the line.

There are some other methods also, check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Comment: Primitives only, for complex data types you need a `toString()` method.

Comment: Yeah! I missed that, Edited. Thanks

Comment: @ Khemraj there are only two (from the content understood) overloading methods that simply take different types (boolean x or String x) , I understand correctly?

Comment: No, there are some other available methods also, see documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i think its like our system understands the 0 and 1 where 1 we consider for true only so we can differentiate between the System.out.println(1);
                                   and
                              System.out.println(true);
only in output but the inner compilation result is same as 1 i.e stated as true in second print statement